# JS как запретить ввод одних пробелов?

Tags: javascript

```
      textarea.onkeyup = function (e) {
            var k = e.keyCode;
            if (k == 32) {
                // нажат пробел
                this.value = ''
            }
```

в таком случае режет все пробелы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверяйте значение самого поля, а не значение нажатой кнопки.

```
textarea.onkeyup = function () {
    if (this.value.match(/^[ ]+$/)) { // В значении только пробелы
        this.value = ''
    }
}
```